# How to use a single filter on a multi functioning table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Apologies for the poor description, but I don't know how to word it.

Essentially I have a supply chain mapped in an excel file, it looks a little something like this

| Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier A | Supplier 1 | Supplier x |
| Supplier A | Supplier 2 | Supplier y |
| Supplier A | Supplier 3 | Supplier z |
| Supplier B | Supplier 4 | Supplier z |
| Supplier B | Supplier 5 | Supplier 2 |
| Supplier B | Supplier 1 | Supplier v |

Now, I want to upload this table to Power BI and create a single filter on 'Supplier Name' which when selected will only show me that suppliers 'supply chain'

EG if supplier 'x' is selected then i would expect the following return

| Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier A | Supplier 1 | Supplier x |
| Supplier A |  |  |
| Supplier A |  |  |

if supplier '1' is selected i would expect the following return

| Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier A | Supplier 1 | Supplier x |
| Supplier B | Supplier 1 | Supplier v |

Tried Splitting out the tier tables, and creating a master but the joins wont allow this to function as expected